# Text color shows properly with firefox but not with ie

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Im using php and when I click on a submit button, I have some text that appears in red on the same page. This works fine with firefox but the text remains black with IE7 and IE8.

Here's the view code

```
if(isset($file_title)) {
    echo '<text class="validation">'.$file_title.'</text>';
}
```

And the css

```
#content text.validation {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: `<text>` is not an html element. That may be why IE is ignoring it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because ie7 and 8 don't support html5 tags (you can use any custom tags with html5, such as text).

Change the text tag into p/span and fix your css rule and it will work fine.

And when you use proper new HTML5 tags such as article or section, you can use html5shim to fix the backwards issue:

http://www.paulund.co.uk/turn-on-html5-in-ie8-or-lower